# How to find the highest Total value index in the Array?

Tags: java, arrays

> here fundememtal,database are two subjects. same element's on both
>   arrays are for the same student. ( fundemental[0],database[0]--> this
>   is for the student 1 ) . i need to find highest(high rank) to lowest
>   rank students from this program.i declare a sort method and pass the
>   total array and create that array total as ascending.just check it out my attachment photo.
>   [i need to find this rank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9JnG.png)
>
> here is my code.if anybody have unclear, please ask me.

```
import java.util.*;
class Remove{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int [] fundemental={54,34,35,65,87,37};
        int database[]={67,56,45,57,78,89};
        int[] total=new int[database.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < database.length; i++){
            total[i]=fundemental[i]+database[i];
        }
            int [] arrayTot=sort(total);

            int index=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < total.length; j++){
                    if(total[i]==(fundemental[j]+database[j])) 
                    index=i;
                }

            }
    }

    public static int[] sort(int[]total){
        for (int i = total.length; i >0; i--){
            int min=total[0];
            int index=0;
            for (int j =1; j < i; j++)
            {
                if(total[j]<min){
                min=total[j];
                index=j;    

                }
            }
            total[index]=total[i-1];
            total[i-1]=min;
        }
        return total;

    }
}
```

> if anybody has an another idea for find highest rank to lower rand from
>   student's two subject, please code me.

Comment: So what is the question? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use insertion sort to the small array size and swap all arrays

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fundamentals = { 54, 34, 35, 65, 87, 37 };
        int database[] = { 67, 56, 45, 57, 78, 89 };
        int len = database.length;
        int[] total = new int[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            total[i] = fundamentals[i] + database[i];
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j > 0 && total[j] > total[j - 1]; j--) {
                swap(total, fundamentals, database, j, j - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    static void swap(int[] total, int[] fundamentals, int[] database, int i, int j) {
        int temp = total[j];
        total[j] = total[i];
        total[i] = temp;

        temp = fundamentals[j];
        fundamentals[j] = fundamentals[i];
        fundamentals[i] = temp;

        temp = database[i - 1];
        database[i - 1] = database[i];
        database[i] = temp;
    }
```

, output

```
[165, 126, 122, 121, 90, 80]
[87, 37, 65, 54, 34, 35]
[78, 89, 57, 67, 56, 45]
```